# Difference between pd.Categorical and pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, categorical-data

**EDITED**

Based on the answers so far (thank you), I understand what the `CategoricalDType` is and what it's used for. What is the `Categorical` / [categorical array](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html#pandas-categorical) for? Does it have a common use case?

--

I don't understand the difference between `pd.Categorical` and `pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype`. The latter returns a `CategoricalDType` instance and the former return a `Categories` instance. What is a `Categorical` object? How do they differ? How are they related? When should I use one rather than the other?

```
type(pd.Categorical(['a','b'],ordered=True))
Out[187]: pandas.core.arrays.categorical.Categorical

type(pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(['a','b'], ordered=True))
Out[188]: pandas.core.dtypes.dtypes.CategoricalDtype
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use pd.CategoricalDtype to change the data type of a series to a category.

For example, you have series with string dtype like this:

```
s = pd.Series(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'])
```

and

`s.dtype` returns:

```
dtype('O')
```

Now, you can create a categorical dtype using the following:

```
s_dtype = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(['b','a'], ordered=True)
```

Then, you can use `pd.Series.astype` to change that data with a sorting of b < a.

```
s.astype(s_dtype).sort_values()
```

Output:

```
2    b
3    b
0    a
1    a
dtype: category
Categories (2, object): ['b' < 'a']
```

Where as,

```
s = pd.Categorical(['a','b'],ordered=True)
```

is a [categorical array](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html#pandas-categorical) constructor.

Answer (score 3):

To complement @Scott's answer, a [`CategoricalDtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalDtype.html) is very useful when you want to maintain a common Categorical across different objects.

Let's consider for example:

```
s1 = pd.Series(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'])
s2 = pd.Series(['a', 'c', 'b', 'b'])
```

If we convert to a generic Categorical and `concat`, then the resulting Series falls back to object since the categories are not common:

```
out1 = pd.concat([s1.astype('category'),
                  s2.astype('category')])

0    a
1    a
2    b
3    b
0    a
1    c
2    b
3    b
dtype: object
```

Now using a common `CategoricalDtype` ensures to maintain this dtype after combining the Series:

```
cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(['a', 'b', 'c'])
out2 = pd.concat([s1.astype(cat),
                  s2.astype(cat)])

0    a
1    a
2    b
3    b
0    a
1    c
2    b
3    b
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Other example:

```
cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(['a', 'b', 'c'], ordered=True)
out = s1.astype(cat) < s2.astype(cat)

0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you, @mozway.  I appreciate your extension and explanation with a very good example. +1